# Install a deleted homebrew formulae

Tags: macos, homebrew, clang

Recently, `homebrew` decided to remove `clang-omp` from the list of formulae available to install from. Is there any way to retrieve it? Or would I have to download and build `clang-omp` bit manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so after looking at how packages leave [`homebrew`'s repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/c57e307). To acquire a "removed" install, one only needs to either:

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/<formula>
```

OR

```
brew tap homebrew/boneyard
brew install <formula>
```

So, in the case of `clang-omp`, it would be with:

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/clang-omp
```

Comment: This isn't working for pyside. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like homebrew just deprecated the boneyard tap in [`PR 314`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/pull/314). Let me get back to you....